# Missing visualforce page component

Tags: visualforce, community

I am wanting to add a visualforce page onto a salesforce community but I don't have the visualforce page component in experience builder. I can not find anything in the documentation that explains why it's missing?

[image]

Comment: In addition to the "available for lightning communities" checkbox you could also check security settings for your page. Is it available for profiles that access your community?

Answer (score 3):

Have you ensured the checkbox " Available for Lightning Experience, Lightning Communities, and the mobile app" is checked on the VF page?

Despite this, if you are still unable to see the Visualforce component in the content section of the builder, please [log a case with salesforce support](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workcom_contact_support.htm&type=5) asking to enable the permission "VisualForce Support in Communities"

-Regards,
Salesforce Support

Comment: Thanks Swetha, the checkbox is enabled. I will log a case with Salesforce support and see how that goes.

Comment: Salesforce enabled visualforce support, thanks Swetha.